# How to hide everything below an <hr> html label?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have the following html template:

```html
<!-- You must include this JavaScript file -->
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>

<!-- For the full list of available Crowd HTML Elements and their input/output documentation,
      please refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-ui-template-reference.html -->

<!-- You must include crowd-form so that your task submits answers to MTurk -->
<crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">

  <crowd-instructions link-text="View instructions" link-type="button">
    <short-summary>
      <p>Provide a brief instruction here</p>
    </short-summary>

    <detailed-instructions>
      <h3>Provide more detailed instructions here</h3>
      <p>Include additional information</p>
    </detailed-instructions>

    <positive-example>
      <p>Provide an example of a good answer here</p>
      <p>Explain why it's a good answer</p>
    </positive-example>

    <negative-example>
      <p>Provide an example of a bad answer here</p>
      <p>Explain why it's a bad answer</p>
    </negative-example>
  </crowd-instructions>

  <div>
    <p>What is your favorite color for a bird?</p>
    <crowd-input name="favoriteColor" placeholder="example: pink" required></crowd-input>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Check this box if you like birds</p>
    <crowd-checkbox name="likeBirds" checked="true" required></crowd-checkbox>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>On a scale of 1-10, how much do you like birds?</p>
    <crowd-slider name="howMuch" min="1" max="10" step="1" pin="true" required></crowd-slider>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Write a short essay describing your favorite bird</p>
    <crowd-text-area name="essay" rows="4" placeholder="Lorem ipsum..." required></crowd-text-area>
  </div>

<hr>

</crowd-form>
```

I would like to hide the submit button. However, as I am using some predifined html elements I do not have control over the submit button. **Therefore, how to hide everything below `<hr>` label?**

**Update**

From one of the answers I tried the following:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!-- You must include this JavaScript file -->
    <script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js">
    
    let elements = document.querySelector('[data-testid=crowd-submit]');
elements.style.display="none";
    
    </script>

    <!-- For the full list of available Crowd HTML Elements and their input/output documentation,
          please refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-ui-template-reference.html -->

    <!-- You must include crowd-form so that your task submits answers to MTurk -->
    <crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">

      <crowd-instructions link-text="View instructions" link-type="button">
        <short-summary>
          <p>Provide a brief instruction here</p>
        </short-summary>

        <detailed-instructions>
          <h3>Provide more detailed instructions here</h3>
          <p>Include additional information</p>
        </detailed-instructions>

        <positive-example>
          <p>Provide an example of a good answer here</p>
          <p>Explain why it's a good answer</p>
        </positive-example>

        <negative-example>
          <p>Provide an example of a bad answer here</p>
          <p>Explain why it's a bad answer</p>
        </negative-example>
      </crowd-instructions>

      <div>
        <p>What is your favorite color for a bird?</p>
        <crowd-input name="favoriteColor" placeholder="example: pink" required></crowd-input>
      </div>

      <div>
        <p>Check this box if you like birds</p>
        <crowd-checkbox name="likeBirds" checked="true" required></crowd-checkbox>
      </div>

      <div>
        <p>On a scale of 1-10, how much do you like birds?</p>
        <crowd-slider name="howMuch" min="1" max="10" step="1" pin="true" required></crowd-slider>
      </div>

      <div>
        <p>Write a short essay describing your favorite bird</p>
        <crowd-text-area name="essay" rows="4" placeholder="Lorem ipsum..." required></crowd-text-area>
      </div>

    <hr>

    </crowd-form>
```

However, the "submit" button is still rendered in the view of the page:

[image]

Comment: Seems like there is only one `crowd-button` element. Would it be possible for you to just get that element and hide it?

Comment: To me it looks like there's something missing in your template, because currently there is nothing else below the `<hr>` tag.

Comment: if everything after the hr is a sibling, you could use `hr ~ * {display:none}`

Comment: @knosmos, yes it could be possible, any idea or example about how to do that?

Comment: @Hoargarth, yes I agree, but that's an official example of the template. It is incomplete, do you know any trick for hidding the submit button?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("crowd-button")[0].style.display = "none"`

Comment: Thanks @knosmos, I tried to add however, it is not working, could you provide an example?

Comment: @Pete, I tried to add that to the style of the example, however, it is not working, could you provide a full example?

Comment: What methods do you have to insert it? How would you run JS if you cannot edit the HTML?

Comment: you need to show your rendered html so we have a clue what the structure you are trying to style is (see [mcve]) - your current code doesn't show anything after the hr tag so I cannot comment or answer more than I have

Comment: I would need to insert a `get_element` method. Something like this: `  function get_element("crowd-button") {
  document.getElementsByTagName("crowd-button")[0].style.display = "none"
  return false;

  }`

Comment: Thanks @Pete, however, it is more simpler than that, I just want to remove the submit button from that view

Comment: I see no submit button in the code you have provided therefore I vote to close as off topic

Comment: I updated the question @Pete, that's the problem, the ajax library Amazon use doesnt give you a way to control that button. That's the reason I want to know in what other ways I can control it

Comment: @Pete the button is somehow created by the crowd-elements script.

Comment: @knosmos, that's correct, any idea about how to hide it or at least control it?

Comment: @knosmos you can still inspect it, view the html and copy the source into the question, there is no way for us to answer this without the html layout - as you can see from all the answers and comments, all we get back is that doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `display:none` via css using `[data-testid=crowd-submit]` .

***Demo Code*** :

```css
[data-testid=crowd-submit] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>
<crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">

  <crowd-instructions link-text="View instructions" link-type="button">
    <short-summary>
      <p>Provide a brief instruction here</p>
    </short-summary>

    <detailed-instructions>
      <h3>Provide more detailed instructions here</h3>
      <p>Include additional information</p>
    </detailed-instructions>

    <positive-example>
      <p>Provide an example of a good answer here</p>
      <p>Explain why it's a good answer</p>
    </positive-example>

    <negative-example>
      <p>Provide an example of a bad answer here</p>
      <p>Explain why it's a bad answer</p>
    </negative-example>
  </crowd-instructions>

  <div>
    <p>What is your favorite color for a bird?</p>
    <crowd-input name="favoriteColor" placeholder="example: pink" required></crowd-input>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Check this box if you like birds</p>
    <crowd-checkbox name="likeBirds" checked="true" required></crowd-checkbox>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>On a scale of 1-10, how much do you like birds?</p>
    <crowd-slider name="howMuch" min="1" max="10" step="1" pin="true" required></crowd-slider>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Write a short essay describing your favorite bird</p>
    <crowd-text-area name="essay" rows="4" placeholder="Lorem ipsum..." required></crowd-text-area>
  </div>

  <hr>

</crowd-form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach (tested with the above defined structure):

```
let elements = document.querySelector('[data-testid=crowd-submit]');
elements.style.display="none";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Daniel, I tried to add it to the `<script></script>`  block, however, it is not working for me, could you provide the full example?

Comment: @knosmos and Daniel, I updated the question with more details so you can see what happen

Comment: Please have the script at the bottom of the page. Script should be loaded once the Dom elements are loaded